# XCode 7 - same file opened in different tabs

Tags: xcode, file, tabs, behavior

I'm angry about the behaviour of xcode opening the same file multiple time.

For example if I've opened api.h and main.m. api.h is #included in main.m. When I do 'jump to definition' of a variable instantiated in main.m which is declared in api.h - xcode does open api.h in a new tab.

So api.h is open twice at a time in the same window. How is it possible to change the behaviour that way, that it's jumping to the tab where it is already opened (when I jump to definition from within main.m)?